# Where to store static contents

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Recently I am developing a new feature for my web application that must be ***Release Independent***.

The feature requires to show some predefined data. Those data will rarely be changed or updated. Here is the part I am confused of. What will be the more appropriate approach to read the data from. There are two options in my hand -

> i) read data from DB
>   ii) read data from text files at some directories

Since this feature must be release independent that means whenever I need to change the data there must not be any application *release* for this. Therefore I can't store the data in **Enum** class.

If I store data in DB there will be some extra work to do like- building a  UI to persist data.

Since the data will hardly change in my point of view storing the data at text files in some directory outside the application will be more likely to be the better approach. But my concern is, whether following the this approach will cause any security issue, bad application performance or not.

Note:
a) I use `javascript` to show the data by populating DOM
b) data is served by a `spring rest controller`

Comment: To me using some third party CDN seems like a reasonable idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here you're using Spring boot.
Spring boot allows you to easily create a centralised configuration server from which clients can read their configuration.
The server can store its data using a variety of means, including a git repository, database, etc.

[centralised configuration example](http://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/)

A simpler way is to have an application.properties (or .yml) file somewhere on the classpath or supplied on the commandline, as detailed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: thanks for enlighten me with a new approach. but `application.properties` file will not meet my purpose. As the data is basically `html` content. And for clarification I am using `spring-mvc`

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon application.properties can hold the location (specific to each installation) where the html files are stored. That way you can have a separate directory for each installation, with application.properties telling each installation where to look.

Comment: If the data is static HTML data, why isnt your front end loading it from a static web server, rather than a spring mvc controller?